# Querying Outlook Mail Items using VSTO

Tags: outlook, vsto

I'm planning to develop a VSTO Outlook add in to generate some statistics on mails (count of mails by day, month, dayOfWeek, domain, sender, attachment# - that kind of thing).

I can iterate each mail folder and individual mails to gather these statistics, but having done this once, I don't want to have to do a full iteration again. 
I'd like to be able to query the mailboxes e.g.

"Show me all of the mails received/sent since %DateTime%", or better, 
"Show me all of the mails received/sent since %Mail_Identifer%".

Is this kind of querying possible or some other mechanism that will allow me skip over 'old' mails?

I'm using VS2008 and targeting Outlook 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a query using the [`Items.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.find.aspx) method? See also:

- [Doing more with Outlook filter and SQL DASL syntax](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewdelin/archive/2005/05/11/416312.aspx)
- [Filtering items using query keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147590.aspx)
- [Filtering items using string comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147583.aspx)
- [Other examples](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=291161)